# Jenkins - Artifact handling

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, webserver, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins set-up consisting of one Master and two Slaves. I have Jenkins jobs (which run only on the slaves) which will create binaries on every commit. Currently, Jenkins archives these artifacts into some place within the Jenkins Master. When i wish to download the binaries using a bash shell script, i use `wget url_link_to_particular_artifact`. I wish to change this. I want to copy all the generated artifacts into one common location on the master node. So, the url would remain the same and only the last part would change with respect to the generated binary name. I label my binaries with tags so it is easy to retrieve them later on. Now, is there a plugin which will copy artifacts into the master node but to the location that I can provide. The master and slave nodes are all redhat linux machines.

I have already gone through the Artifactory Plugin and I do not wish to use it. I want something really simple to implement. Is there really a need for a web server to be running at the location on the master where I wish to copy the artifacts into? Can i transfer the artifacts from slave to master over SSH? If yes, how?

**EDIT:**

I have made some progress and I am sort of stuck now: Assuming we have a web-server on the Jenkins master node that is running. Is it possible for the slave nodes to send the artifacts to this location and the web-server sort of writes it into the file system at that location on the Master??

Comment: Have you tried the other [Artifact Deployer plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin)? Alternatively you could probably run a [post build task/script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task)

Comment: I think we can deploy artifacts to only the slave nodes (node where the build runs) using Artifact Deployer. I would like to copy it to the Master node. Yes, the script is in my mind but I want that as a last resort. If there are already nice plugins available, then I would like to leverage that use initially.

Comment: It's been a while since I last configured a distributed job and I don't have access to such a system for a quick test, but if I'm not mistaking, Jenkins automatically transfers on the master artifacts built on slaves, at least for archival purposes. If that's not the case you can use the [copy to slave plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) to transfer files to and from the slaves.

Comment: Could I copy artifacts back to master but to a place other than the Job's workspace on the master node using the copy to slave plugin? I could not find the right documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This, of course, is possible, but let me explain to you, why this is a bad idea.

Jenkins is not your artifact repository. Indeed you can store your artifacts in Jenkins, but it was not designed to do so. If you will do that for most of your jobs, you will run into problems with disk space, etc. or even race condition with names. 
Not to mention that you don't want to have hundreds or thousands of files in one directory.

Better approach would be to use an artifact repository, such as Nexus to store your artifacts. You can manage and retrieve them easily thru different channels.

Keep in mind that it would be nice to keep your Jenkins in stateless mode and version control your configuration for easy restoration.

If you still want to store your artifacts in one web location, I'd suggest to setup an nginx server, proxy /jenkins calls to jenkins and /artifacts to your artifacts directory.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your answer. This is just a temporary fix for solving the problem. These artifacts are just binaries which later go for regression testing, etc. So not more than 2-3 artifacts would need to be present at any period of time. Coming to the second part of your answer, can't there be a plugin which will make the slaves send the artifacts to a web server on the master and that server writes it into the filesystem? I do not wish to proxy calls because i need two copies of the artifacts - one in `$JENKINS_HOME` and other at this particular location.

Comment: Jenkins should have allowed storing artifacts on a separate location. This would eliminate the problem of disk space.